# Could a human-sized flea really jump over the Eiffel Tower?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, estimation, biology, scaling

I am puzzled why so many people think such a large flea could jump as high as the Eiffel Tower. We know that a 3mm long flea can jump 150mm, which is 50 times its own length. So I suppose it's reasonable to think a 6ft flea could jump 300ft high, but is it?

As I see it, he energy E required to jump to a height H is given by E = WxH, where W is the weight of the flea. Therefore, H = E/W, which should be constant if we assume the energy in a muscle is proportional to its weight or mass. So, no matter how big the flea is, it will always jump to the same height.

Is there a flaw in my argument?

Comment: **FWIW:** the _strength_ of muscles and the strength of bones and other connective tissues only scales with the cross-sectional area. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law#Biomechanics

Comment: The point of the comparison is not to say that a real human sized flea could jump over the Eiffel Tower. It's just a way to get a scale for what "jumping 50 times your own height" means.

Comment: Solomon, you need to take the contraction length of the muscle into account. By strength, I assume you mean force. This means that the Energy available in a muscle is proportional to Force x Length = cross-section Area x Length = volume, which is proportional to Mass.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a flaw in your argument. In fact, it more or less checks out for a variety of jumping animals, be that fleas, grasshoppers, humans, or horses, that their vertical jump is roughly similar, with some generous margin of error. As the work $W$ required to jump a vertical distance $h$ is proportional to the mass $m$ and the height,

$W \propto mh$,

and the available energy from a muscle is proportional to that muscle's mass, they sort of cancel out, if we assume a high percentage of muscle for a given body mass, and do not take into account different types of muscle action, as fleas and other insects do not have muscle fibers in the classic sense. As a first approximation, it holds.

So, the common analogy that a human-sized flea would jump the Eiffel Tower or a human-sized ant could lift a car with it's mandibles do not actually work, because these feats do not scale like this with size. And that is without consideration to the square-cube law that would not even allow such huge insects...

You might be interested in this [document](http://www.yorku.ca:60080/c07ef90f0902560905e21f069bd181a017450821/5bdaa369-b14f-f0e1-d64f-c45bdcce71e4/tap2_Y6WUY7_dec/03_Flea_Jump.pdf) from the University of York's website that follows this train of thought a little more deeply.

Comment: Sorry John, your York University link is broken. Out of interest, I found a biological argument that totally ignores considerations of energy - why? It predicts the giant flea would self destruct if it tried. Here’s the paper https://aphidsrus.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/if-a-flea-were-the-size-of-a-human-could-it-really-jump-over-the-eiffel-tower/

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s the lifting force that is relevant to the work performed in lifting a weight. To get the units right, you need to include gravity. 
Work = mass x g x height

Comment: Since g is a constant in this scenario, I left it out and put the "proportional to" sign instead. I'm sorry the link is dead, it worked when I posted it. The considerations and results are the same as in my answer though.

Comment: Sorry John, I ignored your “proportional to” sign. It’s interesting that this discussion explains why different animals sizes jump to similar heights, depending on their biological makeup. When I said to my physicist son that a flea sized human could still jump the same height as a full sized human, he was reluctant to believe it. Incidentally, I need to study the square-cube law you mention.